# Best way to filter files in gulp.watch?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I would like to watch all, but the .min.ext files in my directories with **gulp.js**. What is the best way to filter out those?

Example:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(e) {
   gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['css']); // don't want to watch .min.js files. what is best way?
});
```

**EDIT:** If can't be done without external packages, which one is the most reputable?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`gulp.watch` internally uses [`vinyl-fs`](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs) (see [source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/d9d44bb26f33c7c13a0b2da68a153d22ee8dd286/index.js#L40)), which uses [`gaze`](https://github.com/shama/gaze), which uses itself [`minimatch`](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch), so you should be able to ignore some files using `!./js/*.min.*`.

In fact, this is even described in [vinyl-fs's README](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs#usage):

```
fs.src(["./js/**/*.js", "!./js/vendor/*.js"])
[…]
```

Comment: This works too `./js/!(vendor)/**/*.js`, so you only need one entry in the watch

Comment: `gulp@3.9.1` uses `vinyl-fs@0.3.0` which uses `glob-watcher@^0.0.6` (best match is `0.0.8`) which uses `gaze@^0.5.1` (best match is `0.6.4`) which uses `globule~0.2.0` which uses `minimatch@~0.2.11`AND `glob~3.2.7` which produces interesting results...

Any match not starting with `!` will return ALL paths from that match, and any match starting with `!` will then filter the resulting array. Be wary if you use `**/*` and then filter it as it will take a long time. [Relevant code](https://github.com/cowboy/node-globule/blob/v0.2.0/lib/globule.js#L23-L39)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in gulp 4, the fix is as follows

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch(['js/*.js','!js/*.min.js'], css);
});
```

`css` is `gulp.series`/`gulp.parallel` or any function that you want to run.