# Gulp watch only SCSS files (Laravel elixir)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I've a gulp task which combined all the SCSS and javascript use on the site. However while developing I usually use "gulp watch" command and it watches all files both, javascript and css.

The question is how can make gulp watch and combine only SCSS (app.scss) files? I tried to look into the gulp watch task and somehow it doesn't work for me.

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    elixir = require('laravel-elixir'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
    require('laravel-elixir-livereload');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');

    mix.styles([
            'app.css',
        ], null, 'public/css')
        .styles([
            ... frontend css files ..
        ],'public/css/core.css' ,'resources/vendor')
        // Admin CSS (core.css)
        .styles([
            ... admin css files ..
        ], 'public/assets/admin/css/core.css', 'resources/vendor');

    mix.scripts([
            ... core javascripts files ..
        ], null, 'resources/vendor')
        .scripts(['app.js'], 'public/js/app.js')
        .scripts([
            ... frontend javascripts files ..
        .scripts([
            ... backend javascripts files ..
        // Dashboard.js
        .scripts([
            'dashboard.js'
        ], 'public/assets/admin/js/dashboard.js');

});
```

"gulp styles" works but it won't keep watching so I've to run it manually.

Comment: have you tried chaining them?

Comment: @CanCelik by chaining you mean using the pipe() function right?

Comment: Oh wait sorry I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605592/best-way-to-filter-files-in-gulp-watch

Comment: @CanCelik Thanks I will try that, also chaining functions seem to help a little bit, now it only compiles CSS files when SCSS file is changed.