# How to ignore node_modules directory from gulp:watch?

Tags: javascript, gulp, node-modules

I have a gulp script that watches for code changes in all `javascript files`. It looks like this:

`gulp.watch(['./**/*.jsx', './**/*.js'], ['build:react']);`

So, it watches for all `.js` and `.jsx` files from root directory, but I want to ignore `node_modules` directory. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605592/best-way-to-filter-files-in-gulp-watch

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use `gulp unwatch` This removes the folder specified from your pipe. However, it's generally a good idea to have a `source` folder that gulp watches instead of the project root folder (then the `.git` directory and all sorts will be caught up in your task.